# Why Typre III results is different from lsmeans results in Proc glimmix

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I am using Proc glimmix to run a random intercept model on a continuous outcome over five time points. Table Type III indicates sex is not significant while the 95% CIs of male and females in table lsmeans have no overlap. I wonder how to explain this discrepancy? When I look at the male and female outcomes over time I also expect a significant higher outcome for males as the CIs in the second table say. Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect to test the significance of a difference based on seeing if the CIs for the means overlap. The means and the difference of the means are two different statistical animals, with their own distributions and their own standard errors. The SE of the difference M - F is `sqrt(SE(M)^2 + SE(F)^2 -2*Cov(M,F))`. and that can be vastly different from `SE(M) + SE(F)` which is implicitly assumed when you compare confidence intervals. Moreover, in a mixed model,the degrees of freedom can differ vastly, and that covariance term can be anything.

To get SAS to compute the right estimates, use an `ESTIMATE` statement to construct the desired quantity.

Comment: It also seems like you probably should have time as a class variable, rather than modeling it as continuous.

Comment: Thanks Russ! I put variable time in the class line and now the estimates look more plausible.